# pay amount to external users in stripe

Tags: flutter, mobile, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm developing an app having customers and sellers. For payments I'm using stripe API. I've already completed the customer part by accepting the payment from them on purchase through their cards. Now I want to transfer payments to the sellers, but stripe doesn't provide the feature to transfer payment to the bank accounts of external users.

I tried creating Stripe accounts of sellers from API using stripe connect, but they are showing as restricted and require business information of every seller which I don't have.

If anyone knows a solution and has an alternative, kindly help me.

Comment: The correct way to do this is with Stripe Connect. That way the customer is paying the seller directly - and you just get a service fee/percent. It's up to the Stripe Connect seller to supply that information - so that Stripe can "know their customer". If *you* accept the payments, *you* become the seller and have all the responsibilities of a seller (including chargebacks etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario. I sent an e-mail to the support team and they said that currently stripe does not support direct transfer but may in future. **You can transfer amount to those users who are registered with you as a stripe connect user and for that you have to force user to register on stripe.**

- You can register on some other platform like:

https://developers.dwolla.com/guides/send-money/create-a-customer

**OR**

- You can provide a gift voucher to the user:

https://help.giftup.com/article/188-stripe-subscriptions-coupons